# AJAX: Pass a value to ajax method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Ive tried a couple out-of-the-box ways trying to get my value into my ajax but everytime I get js error's. Hopefully one of you can help.

I have the following JQuery Ajax:

```
 $("#usertasklist").click(function () {
    $('#basicModal4').modal('hide');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Home/GetAjaxUserTasksExecuted",
        data: { filterdate: variable1 },
        datatype: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Succes!");
            var $titleDiv = $('#Modal5Label');
            $titleDiv.replaceWith("<h3><b>User Tasks Executed</b></h3>");
            var $detailDiv = $('#superdatadivthing3');
            $detailDiv.replaceWith(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("Error!");
        },
        complete: function () {

            $('#basicModal5').modal('show');
            console.log("Complete!");
        }
    });
});
```

And a viewbag in my controller

```
 Session["Usercode"];
```

How can I pass the value from my view bag to replace "variable1" in the data section of my ajax call?

Comment: Ignore any answers suggesting you inject it dynamically into your script. That has all sorts of problems. Instead inject it (e.g. as a `data-filter` attribute on the body) into the page and pick that up with `$('body').data('filter');` If you must inject into script, use a simple standalone global var.

Comment: why do you need to get from ajax something which is already in session? What if I change the variable1 value with another user code in the ajax request?

Comment: You can use hidden control and fetch the value from there

Comment: Thanks for the reply's, Could you post an example of what you suggested TrueBlue?

Answer (score 0):

How about getting the data from a container?

HTML-example

```
<table id="YOURDIVHERE">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <span>data which i will use</span>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Your Ajax-call

```
 $("#usertasklist").click(function () {
    $('#basicModal4').modal('hide');
   var data = innerXHTML($('#YOURDIVHERE').attr('id'));
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Home/GetAjaxUserTasksExecuted",
        data: { filterdate: data },
        datatype: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Succes!");
            var $titleDiv = $('#Modal5Label');
            $titleDiv.replaceWith("<h3><b>User Tasks Executed</b></h3>");
            var $detailDiv = $('#superdatadivthing3');
            $detailDiv.replaceWith(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("Error!");
        },
        complete: function () {

            $('#basicModal5').modal('show');
            console.log("Complete!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you post an example of what the div would look like please? Edit: I created the code as you suggested but it doesn't recognize innerXHTML.

Comment: It can basically be any HTML inside a div. IN "my" div there was a table which I included as data when posting data for sending with an email. I justed parsed the tabledata server-side to get the mail content.